# how to save my single .sql script into different files

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, cmd, split

My script has queries like
"if exists index1
drop index1"

"if exists index2
drop index2"

"if exists index3
drop index3"

and so on.............................

i want to save each query into a separate .sql script. is there any automatic way? please help

Comment: Please show us some code on what you have tried. Look here on [How to ask Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if you are trying to save one .sql script file into multiple .sql files then you need to query your each scripts into multiple scrips and save them all one by one

Answer (score 0):

it appears you are looking to script each sql server object to a different file (if so) this might help you :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18240347/2628302