# Import 10,000+ stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I need to import 10,000+ stored procedures from a clients environment into my company's environment.

One option is to create a C# based application which creates these 10K+ stored procedures.

I have knowledge of DataSet, DataReader etc. but I do not know how to implement this.

Another option - I have created an SSIS package using a ForEachLoop, taking files from folder and loads/executes in DB using Execute SQL Task. This takes too much time (2000 files = 1 hour)

So can you guys give me...some thoughts..ideas..

Comment: Can you get the scripts  from their source control system. Database code should be in source control like any other code.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer stored procedures, functions, views and many other object types I would use the generate script wizard.  You can run the generated scripts in the new environment using SSMS.

Comment: Thanks Joe, but i found that that way resulting script is Too Large. When i tried that approach & copied .SQL files from Client machine & opened in my Local SSMS, System got hang-up. Also there is little danger/doubt when we open too big file in SSMS, that file might not load/open completely. So i am looking for another alternative.

Comment: someone suggested to try for Transfer Database Objects in SSIS. But that task transfer objects between 2 DB only, we cannot give source connection as File-Type connection.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that might work for you if you have the necessary database permissions is to use the ‘sp_helptext’ system procedure. With this approach you won’t need to develop a C# app.

The first step is to create a temporary database that will hold the stored procedure content:

```
USE [master]

GO

CREATE DATABASE StoredProcBackup;

GO

USE [StoredProcBackup]

GO

CREATE TABLE StoredProcedures
(
     [ProcedureName] NVARCHAR(200)  Primary Key
    ,[ProcedureContent] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

In the above table the  StoredProcedures table will hold the names and content of the stored procedures you are trying to script out.
The next step is to create a cursor that enumerates the procedure and write the content to the StoredProcedures table in the newly created StoredProcBackup database.

```
DECLARE @procedureName NVARCHAR(200) ;
DECLARE @procedureContent NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @procedureContentTable TABLE
(
    [Text] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

TRUNCATE TABLE [StoredProcBackup].[dbo].[StoredProcedures];


DECLARE procedure_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
FROM information_schema.routines 
WHERE routine_type = 'PROCEDURE';

OPEN procedure_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM procedure_cursor   
INTO @procedureName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    SET @procedureContent = '';

    INSERT INTO @procedureContentTable
    EXEC dbo.sp_helptext @procedureName;

    select @procedureContent = coalesce(@procedureContent , '') +  convert(NVARCHAR(MAX),[Text])
    from @procedureContentTable;

    DELETE @procedureContentTable;

    INSERT INTO [StoredProcBackup].[dbo].[StoredProcedures]
    (
        [ProcedureName]
        ,[ProcedureContent]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @procedureName
        ,@procedureContent
    );



    FETCH NEXT FROM procedure_cursor   
    INTO @procedureName;

END 

CLOSE procedure_cursor;
DEALLOCATE procedure_cursor;
```

You can now backup the ‘StoredProcBackup’ database and restore on your local server. Once you have a copy on the local server you can simply run the following script to restore the stored procedures.

```
USE [StoredProcBackup]

DECLARE @procedureContent NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE create_procedure_cursor CURSOR FOR   
SELECT  [ProcedureContent]
FROM    [dbo].[StoredProcedures]

OPEN create_procedure_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM create_procedure_cursor   
INTO @procedureContent;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    EXEC (@procedureContent);

    SET @procedureContent = '';

    FETCH NEXT FROM create_procedure_cursor   
    INTO @procedureContent;

END 

CLOSE create_procedure_cursor;
DEALLOCATE create_procedure_cursor;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Edmond. You gave me nice solution without asking much question. I got similar thought like above, but due to time constraints I created SSIS Package & using that i am deploying Individual Stored Procedures (in .SQL File), into destination DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can just backup the database and restore it again. How big is the database ?

Comment: Due to privacy & security reasons, we cannot use this approach.

Comment: So what is the use of the stored proc without relevant tables ? you can't run it. I don't think you can just transfer stored proc between databases, because stored proc is stored as meta data in the database. As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240194/how-to-script-out-stored-procedures-to-files

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned C# and that's not a bad approach. Or, more generally, MS provides a .NET library called SMO (SQL Management Objects) that makes things like this not so bad. In a comment to another answer, you mentioned the size of the file. Specifically, I'd take a look at the Server and Database objects (and the StoredProcedures collection for the latter). Arbitrarily pick some number of procedures you want to put into a given file and iterate over the list of stored procedures. Once you've put in as many as you want to put in one file, increment the file name and keep scripting.

Comment: Thank you very much Ben. You gave me nice solution without asking much question. I got similar thought like above,and i tried also, but somehow there was issue with SMO related DLL. Due to time constraints I created SSIS Package & using that i am deploying Individual Stored Procedures (in .SQL File), into destination DB.

Comment: No problem. I know that exploring SMO has given me a better understanding of how things are laid out in the database. So even though your problem is solved, spending some time learning this won't be wasted.