# SSIS packages which scripts all my stored procedures to .sql files

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am looking for a SSIS packages which scripts all my stored procedures to `.sql` files

I am in the middle of the ocean, what to do and how to do.

Query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID), definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
```

Expectation (to my local folder)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be directly done from SQL Server management studio and this has been answered on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240194/how-to-script-out-stored-procedures-to-files)  by Aaron Bertrand. By chance, you don't have permissions to run this from SSMS you can try to query the object definition from the `sys.sql_modules` table using an object ID.

Hoping this helps you out with your problem.

Comment: Actually I am looking for each row for each .sql files