# Scheduled Script Backup SSIS, SP etc

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssis, database-backups

I'm looking for a script or SSIS process I can run that will allow me to schedule daily backups of all views, UDFs, and stored procedures. I accomplish this manually now from within SSMS via Right-click DB --> tasks --> generate scripts. I've done quite a bit of research on here and found one method that uses sp_cmdshell which I am not allowed to use for security reasons, etc... Is there any way to mimic the script that is generated using the above method of clicking around in SSMS?

Thanks much!

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240194/how-to-script-out-stored-procedures-to-files

Comment: Post mentions the same method I wrote about above (Generate scripts task) and the other commands don't seem to work.